# Admin edit ... page not found because of alias with characters

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

hi everyone … my problem is in the title 
I can not edit pages that have accent in alias path 
e.g.: [http://localhost:8888/MYSITE/bôbô/ïèéà/my-contënt](http://localhost:8888/MYSITE/b%C3%B4b%C3%B4/%C3%AF%C3%A8%C3%A9%C3%A0/my-cont%C3%ABnt)

i got a page not found .. but i still able to edit my content if i write the same url without any accent
e.g.: [http://localhost:8888/MYSITE/bobo/ieea/my-contënt](http://localhost:8888/MYSITE/bobo/ieea/my-cont%C3%ABnt)

So in a nutshell, if i have custom alias with path that contains characters accents it is NOT OK ( tells me page not found when i want to edit it)
http://localhost:8888/MYSITE/anypath_with_accent_1/anypath_with_accent_2/edit?destination=node/ANYNODE

but if i replace in url

http://localhost:8888/SYDEV/node/ANYNODE/edit?destination=node/ANYNODE

that’s ok i can edit my content

So anyone has any idea to solve that ?

My idea is to force url ( only for admin ) to be node/ANYNODE/edit?destination=node/ANYNODE

But i simply don’t know how and even if it’s possible.

Thank you for advice or solutions

.. and of course i wish you an happy new year !!!

Comment: Are you talking about editing or viewing the nodes? - I'm a little confused. It's hard to tell by your description, whether the URL alias for viewing the content with accented URLs is working or not, and just the '/edit' pages aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard URL aliases of Drupal work for the view URLs only. No matter of enabled transliteration or not.

An example: If you have a content node with ID `10`, then the regular view URI would be `/node/10`, but you can alias it with e.g. `/my-path/my-node`. If you want to edit the node, you still use `/node/10/edit`.

Enabling the redirect module, you can make sure that the content will not be viewable by both URIs `/node/10` AND `/my-path/my-node`, but only by tha aliased version `/my-path/my-node` (which is desirable for avoiding search engine penalties). The edit URI remains being `/node/10/edit`.

In some of your comments (you should add such information to the original question) you stated, that you created automatic alias patterns using the pathauto module to automatically generate the aliases for content.

If your use case requires sub paths as `/edit` to be rewritten to your alias as well, so in above example `/node/10/edit` to `/my-path/my-node/edit`, have a look to the [subpathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module. You might even have it installed and enabled already, as you state that such URIs are working for non-accented aliases.

But be aware, that it's in beta stage and has some bugs in conjunction with the above mentioned rewrite module. So to make the rewrite working with the currently available development version for Drupal 8, you might still have to apply the latest patch from issue [#2875026](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto/issues/2875026).

And if the above patch is applied, but rewriting still doesn't work when you use accented characters in the URL aliases, then you will have to create an according issue within the [subpathauto issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/subpathauto?categories=All), as this is the right place for module specific errors.

Comment: hello yhank you for your answer, redirect module is installed and subpath auto to but my problem is still there ... i can acces to my page (la-féé/enchantée/mypage) but if i want to edit in BO my url doesn't work (la-féé/enchantée/mypage/edit?destination=node/30) but (node/30/edit?destination=node/30) works

Comment: Did you apply above mentioned patch?

Comment: yes i did but still have the same problem .. it keeps accents in my alias

Answer (score 2):

The Pathauto module has an option (*Transliterate prior to creating alias*) which replaces some characters with equivalent characters in the US-ASCII alphabet; for example, it replaces *è* with *e*. By default that is selected, but you can deselect it in /admin/config/search/path/settings.

> [image: screenshot]

There is also another setting that replace the characters with characters in the ASCII-96 set, but as you see from the screenshot, that is disabled by default.

Notice also that page contains other settings that alter the characters present in a path alias, for example the one for the words that should not appear in the path alias, which by default are: *a*, *an*, *as*, *at*, *before*, *but*, *by*, *for*, *from*, *is*, *in*, *into*, *like*, *of*, *off*, *on*, *onto*, *per*, *since*, *than*, *the*, *this*, *that*, *to*, *up*, *via*, *with*.

> [image: screenshot]

As for the *Pathauto i18n* module you installed, that is not ready for Drupal 8. Its code is still for Drupal 7, with the exception of few functions. Drupal 8 will recognize it as Drupal 8 module simply because it has a .info.yml file as requested, but most of the code is still using Drupal 7 functions. That is also the cause of the error you reported in your comment.

Uninstall it, or you will not be even able to visit the settings page of the Pathauto module.

Finally, if you want the path alias to work also, for example, node/30/edit, then you need to install the [*Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)*](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module, which in its project page clearly states:

> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased URL users/admin/contact instead. This also includes Views URLs taking a node as argument (e.g. node/%/yourview), in short, every URL that is based on, or extends, an existing alias. In combination with the Pathauto module it is possible to get rid of all remaining exposed internal non-administrative URLs.

Keep in mind the module is still in beta phase, and check the issues opened for that module, for example [Redirect module causes redirect back to unaliased path](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto/issues/2875026), which is of interest for you if you also use the *Redirect* module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. i 've uninstall  Pathauto i18n module .; so i canacces to path auto settings ( great) . Transliterate prior to creating alias is checked but the probleme  is the same ... ican ecces to my page (la-féé/enchantée/mypage) but if i want to edit in BO my url doesn't work (la-féé/enchantée/mypageedit?destination=node/30) but (node/30/edit?destination=node/30) works ...

Comment: If the transliterate setting is checked, then you should not see letters like _é_ because those are replaced. The Pathauto module doesn't create alias for node/30/alias, but only for node/30. For the other path alias, you need another module.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)? If you are and it's creating the paths, make sure that you have `Transliterate prior to creating alias` checked in the settings, then it will make sure that all of your aliases are being saved with web-safe characters in the URL.

Comment: yes i use it .. i don t see any settings one it . Pathauto i18n is checked .. is there any post  screenshot on the blog ?

Comment: well sorry i tried when looking for admin ( /admin/config/search/path/settings..)   but ali have is The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Call to undefined function language_list() in pathauto_i18n_form_pathauto_settings_form_alter() (line 192 of modules/pathauto_i18n/pathauto_i18n.module).
pathauto_i18n_form_pathauto_settings_form_alter(Array, Object,

Comment: forgot to inform i m on drupal 8

Comment: @JeromeTurpin Notice that the _Pathauto_ module and the _Pathauto i18n_ module are two different modules, and the later doesn't have a ready Drupal 8 version.

Comment: There comes a non-functional placeholder module as submodule of the pathauto module, which for now can just be left non-enabled.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz The problem is that the module contains a .info.yml which makes Drupal 8 think it's a Drupal 8 module. It is true there is a _Unfortunately version for Drupal 8 is not ready yet at all. I'm looking for a help with that._ warning, but the development snapshot for Drupal 8 should not even appear in the project page. Users who want to test it know how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

well in fact i had menu items without node destination ... so breadcrumb shown alias and not title .. i just had to create node destination for items menu and voilà.
Thank you everyne for your help